# VCScommand for VIM

Tags: git, version-control, vim, plugins, mercurial

I am trying to use **HG (Mercurial)** with the Vim [VCScommand](http://code.google.com/p/vcscommand/) plugin, but am running into a problem "***Too many matching VCS:  git HG***".  I removed the **vcsgit.vim** and the HG binding seemed to work.  I thought **VCScommand** used the folder to determine, which VCS one was using.  I guess this is a flawed assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the detection via the `VCSCommandVCSTypeOverride` variable. Most probably you can only get the error you had mentioned if the actual file (and its directory is vc-ed with both git and hg.